# Python user input to bytes

Tags: python, sockets

I am trying to send a message with using sockets in python 3.12. For my script to work I need the data that should be send as bytes so everything like `message = b"text"` works but I have no idea how to get user input in there.

I have tryied encoding the string that the user puts in with `input()` to get it as bytes as I have found this in a different question related to this problem here on stackoverflow but this doesn’t work and I get a bunch of errors from my code like „'bytes' object has no attribute 'copy'“. Has anyone a idea what I could do to get user input into the form message = b"text" as this is the only format that works for me so far.

Comment: Encoding definitely should work. Please show how you tried to do it. `message = input().encode()`

Comment: "but this doesn’t work " **how** does it not work? What is the problem exactly? Please provide a [mcve]. Using a bytes literal to create a `bytes` object and encoding a `str` object to a `bytes` object both result in the *same type of object*, so the issue is somehwere else. If you are getting an error, post the *complete error message including the stack trace*.

Comment: When I try 'message = input().encode()' then I get the error 'TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()' @Barmar

Comment: I can't reproduce that. There's no integer there and no call to `len()`. You'll need to post a [mre] that demonstrates it, the problem is elsewhere in your code.